# Haproxy 1.5dev17 stick-table using cookie doesn't work

Tags: haproxy

M trying to get haproxy stick implementation to work using cookie set response by server as look-up value.

Here's snippet of haproxy conf

----start----

backend bk

```
stick-table type string len 36 size 1m

stick store-response set-cookie(Server-Token)

stick match url_param(token)

server db01 127.0.0.1:8001 maxconn 5 check inter 60000

server db02 127.0.0.1:8002 maxconn 5 check inter 60000
```

---end----

Server sets the cookie and clients stick to corresponding server based on this cookie val as part of request-response via haproxy.

This is not working as expected.While stick "store-response" with "src" as fetch method works.

Kindly help out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried your config and it works perfectly here with dev17. I'm assuming you're having a "defaults" section since your backend doesn't even have the http mode specified. Would you please post it ? I think that the issue is there.

Comment: This is not an answer